# How to add a class to another element when another is active with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title says, I want to add a class i.e. `.show` to an anchor tag, where the class equals the .image_category, for e.g. CNC_Machining. 
(See HTML in DevTools AND/OR PHP row from DB)

The button elements receive the active class when it has been clicked by a user.

This is part of a filterable image gallery. The images are loaded from a DB and displayed in the browser via PHP. This means that the images are already available, it's only about showing them or hiding them with the well-known `display: none;` / `display: block`; attribute.

I believe I must have made an error in the code somewhere, because to the best of my knowledge I have followed instructions from other e.g.

Help would be appreciated.

Please have a look at the relevant code below. So far I have only writen code which includes checks for an active CNC_Machining in order to reduce complexity.

EDIT:
I also indluded the code which assigns ACTIVE to the clicked button. I was reluctant first, because I thought it makes it too complex to analyze, however maybe it will help with trouble shooting.

To make this more palpable:

1. User clicks button CNC_Machining -- active class is assigned to the same button.
2. When active class is assigned to button -- .show class is added to anchor tag  where the class is .CNC_Machining.
3. Image shows in the browser

Here is an image of the HTML in devTools:
[DevTool Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HXKL.png)

JS CODE TO ASSIGN "ACTIVE" CLASS to clicked button:

```
    // The button which would be used to add 'active' class to
    // all the buttons.
    let allButton = document.querySelector('#All');

    let btns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.category-button'));
    let activeButton = null;

    const handleClick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
      // Checks that the activeButton is defined (initially it's null).
      // Also checks that the button that was clicked is not the button which is
      // already active to avoid removing the active class on double click.
      if (activeButton != null && activeButton != e.currentTarget) {
        activeButton.classList.remove('active');
      }
      activeButton = e.currentTarget;
    }

    btns.forEach(node => {
      node.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    });

    // Listen to a click event from the "allButton" and when it's clicked,
    // loop through the buttons array and add 'active' class to all buttons
    // in it.
    allButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        btns.forEach(btn => {
            btn.classList.add('active');
        })
    });

    let category_btn = category_btns.getElementsByClassName('category-');

    category_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      addClassShow(category_btn) 
    });
```

JS CODE TO ASSIGN SHOW CLASS:

```
let category_btns = document.getElementById('category-buttons');
let category_btn = category_btns.getElementsByClassName('category-button');

// if the CNC_Machining button is "active" give anchor tags with .CNC_Machining classes the CSS .show atttribute. 
let category_btn = getElementsByClassName('category-button');

      let CNC_Mach_btn = document.getElementById("CNC_Machining_button");
      let CNC_Machining_Class_In_AnchorTag = document.getElementsByClassName("CNC_Machinery");

      CNC_Mach_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // if the the CNC_Machining button is active make classes with Images with CNC_Machining active. 
        if (CNC_Mach_btn.classList.contains("active")) {
          CNC_Machining_Class_In_AnchorTag.classList.add("show");
        }

    });
```

CSS:

```
#category-buttons {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 12.5%;
  margin: 10vh 10px;
}

.category-button {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(153, 124, 124);
}

.product-gallery-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 65%;
  margin: auto;
}

.gallery-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 13px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  justify-content: center;
}

.images {
  display: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML and PHP CODE from code editor:

```
<div id="category-buttons">
    <h5>Choose image category</h5>
      <button id="All" class="category-button active" >All Categories</button>
      <button id="CNC_Machining_button" class="category-button CNC_Mach_btn">CNC_Machining</button>
      <button id="HP_Die_Casting_button" class="category-button HP_Die_btn">HP Die Casting</button>
      <button id="Iron_Casting" class="category-button">Iron Casting</button>
      <button id="Steel_Casting" class="category-button">Steel Casting</button>
      <button id="Precision_Casting" class="category-button">Precision Casting</button>
      <button id="Aluminium_Casting" class="category-button">Aluminum Casting</button>
    </div>


<section class="gallery-links">
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2 class="product-gallery-title">Product Gallery</h2>

  <div class="gallery-container">
    <?php
    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY orderGallery DESC';
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
      echo 'SQL statement failed!';
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //what's echoed out by the database

        echo '  <a class="images '.$row["image_category"].'" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].')">
                <div class="color-overlay">
                <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
                <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
                </div>
                </a>';
      }
    }


    ?>  

  </div>

</div>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo '<div class="gallery-upload">
    <h3>Please fill in the text fields, select the image and upload to gallery by clicking upload.</h3>
    <form action="includes/gallery-upload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File name...">
      <input type="text" name="fileTitle" placeholder="Image title...">
      <input type="text" name="fileDescription" placeholder="Image Description...">
      <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category....">
      <input type="file" name="imageFile" >
      <br>
      <br>
      <button class="gallery-submit-btn" type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
    </form> 
  </div>';
}
?>
</section>
```

HTML output from browser DEV_Tools:

```
    <html lang="en"><head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="galleryTest.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <title>TEXATREK</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="navi">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/trexatex/trexatek_V4.php">
        <img class="brand-logo" src="../images/logos/Trexatek_Logo_AND_Name_Gold-Orange.png" alt="">
      </a>

      <!--HAMBURGER Toggler Icon-->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- NAVBAR  -> div BELLOW -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-uppercase" id="navbarMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-5 ">
          <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="../trexatek_V4.php">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="../manufacturing.html">Manufacturing</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="/trexatex/PHPGallery/GalleryInPHP.php">Gallery</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

            <div id="category-buttons">
            <h5>Choose image category</h5>
              <button id="All" class="category-button active">All Categories</button>
              <button id="CNC_Machining_button" class="category-button active">CNC_Machining</button>
              <button id="HP_Die_Casting_button" class="category-button">HP Die Casting</button>
              <button id="Iron_Casting" class="category-button">Iron Casting</button>
              <button id="Steel_Casting" class="category-button">Steel Casting</button>
              <button id="Precision_Casting" class="category-button active">Precision Casting</button>
              <button id="Aluminium_Casting" class="category-button">Aluminum Casting</button>
            </div>


      <section class="gallery-links">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <h2 class="product-gallery-title">Product Gallery</h2>



        </div>

          </section>


          <div class="login-container">
          <p>Login area</p>


            <form class="login-form" action="../Login-System/login_user.php" method="POST">
            <input class="login" type="text" name="userName" placeholder="username">
            <br>
            <input class="login" type="text" name="userPassword" placeholder="password">
            <br> <br>
            <button class="login-button" type="submit" name="submit_usrName_and_psw">Sign in</button>
          </form>    

            <br>
            <h3>You currently logged out!</h3>    </div>






    </body><div class="gallery-container">
              <a class="images " style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/asf.UNIQid5c3f6d21e13ba8.48416291.jpg)">
                        <div class="color-overlay">
                        <h3>asf</h3>
                        <p>asdf</p>
                        </div>
                        </a>  <a class="images " style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/1234.UNIQid5c3f6d0fe3b117.37260531.jpg)">
                        <div class="color-overlay">
                        <h3>wqer</h3>
                        <p>qwer</p>
                        </div>
                        </a>  <script src="jsCode.js"></script><a class="images Sand_Casting" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/castingwork.UNIQid5c3769cc010891.70586628.jpg)">
                        <div class="color-overlay">
                        <h3>Caster at work</h3>
                        <p>Image of one of our workers casting</p>
                        </div>
                        </a>  <a class="images HP_Die_Casting" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/cast_pulley.UNIQid5c3723915a1120.39380036.jpg)">
                        <div class="color-overlay">
                        <h3>Precision Molding</h3>
                        <p>Cast Pulley made by PM</p>
                        </div>
                        </a><a class="images CNC_Machinery" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/steelcastminiturbine.UNIQid5c372f45d3fba6.30267243.jpg)">
                        <div class="color-overlay">
                        <h3>MiniTurbine</h3>
                        <p>MiniTurbine from SteelCasting</p>
                        </div>
                        </a>  <a class="images CNC_Machinery" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/galvanized_cast_iron.UNIQid5c3720c4502f92.46784406.jpg)">
                        <div class="color-overlay">
                        <h3>Galvanized_Cast_Iron</h3>
                        <p>Image of connector manufactured in Galvanized_Cast_Iron_Way</p>
                        </div>
                        </a>  <a class="images Sand_Casting" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/pizza-pie.UNIQid5c372f19564787.51280655.jpg)">
                        <div class="color-overlay">
                        <h3>Cool pic</h3>
                        <p>When workers work</p>
                        </div>
                        </a>  <a class="images Sand_Casting" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/greensandmoulding.UNIQid5c372eec267ff2.76912593.jpg)">
                        <div class="color-overlay">
                        <h3>Green Sand Molding</h3>
                        <p>Casting process for Green Sand Molding</p>
                        </div>
                        </a>    

          </div></html>
```

Comment: Your CSS has no `.show` class. Why are you adding/removing `.show` on the buttons? You are unclear in your description: What does "when another becomes active" - what other? Are you using the CSS definition of "active" or your own? etc. etc.

Comment: If you scroll down in the CSS, you should find it. I'll make some edits to the description to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes, your edit now expose the CSS class - what about the rest? Specifically about applying the class to the buttons that you are checking for an active state.

Comment: Your issues might be with JavaScript executing `document` queries, before the document is fully loaded. Without seeing your HTML, it's impossible to say.

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are trying to add/remove a class name from a list of elements and not a specific element. (`getELementsByClassName` returns a NodeList, not a single element).

Comment: Where is the `.HP_Die_Casting` elements in your HTML?

Comment: I have to add some updates, one sec.

Comment: @AndrewL64 Added the image with the .HP_Die_Casting class, please see updated image in link.

Comment: `HP_Die_Casting` is an id but you're trying to retrieve it using `getElementByClassName`. Please copy paste that HTML code from the screenshot in your question.

Comment: @andreL64 Updated HTML/PHP code. HP_Die_Casting is a class in 4th <a>. Also noticed that I have  <script src="jsCode.js"></script> right after 2nd <a>, that's weird.